# SQL query returning more than one result

Tags: sql

This is my SQL query

```
SELECT 
    room.*, reservation.rn, reservation.cin 
FROM 
    room, reservation
```

But it is returning 4 instances of each row.

I just want to get the corresponding reservation from another table where they have same room number and at the same time display the remaining rooms

### Room Table

Id,r_num,r_price,in_date,out_date

### reservation_table

id,r_num,cIn,cOut

Comment: Please, post your database tables

Comment: In what way are Java and PHP involved?

Comment: You have a cross join in your query.

Comment: `... FROM room,reservation` - if you don't provide any where clause your result will contain an entry for _every_ combination of room and reservation, even if they don't match (e.g. room A, reservation for room B etc.).

Comment: sotmething like http://sqlfiddle.com/ could definitely help ;)

Comment: Hint:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax!

Comment: `SELECT room.*,reservation.rn,reservation.cin FROM room join reservation USING(room_no)`

Comment: @GordonLinoff Why you don't recommend commas in the `Form` clause sir ?

Comment: Because it does a cross join. If you don't understand SQL, you're going to have a very hard time writing it.

Comment: @Kayaman and if I do need a cross join , do I still not advised to use commas?

Comment: Where do you need a cross join?

Comment: @Accountantم - You can explicitly write that too - `select * from a cross join b`.

Comment: ..just in case your join is still returning multible rows, you can always limit the result to lets say one: LIMIT 0,1;

Comment: @Kayaman anytime I need it I don't know . for example when I need to join a 1 field derived table to all the rows in the my table. what is the difference between an explicit cross join and comma join, that makes "Gordon Linoff" himself says **"Never"**? . note: *I only want to learn*

Comment: Best practices mostly.  Performance wise they're the same, but if you get in the habit of writing sloppy SQL, it's a pretty downhill trend from there.  Sure it's pretty legible with 2 tables, but if you start throwing 4 or 5 tables at it, stuff starts becoming far more difficult to understand.  Also this method tends to be a little more error prone.

Comment: @Accountantم: if you **really** need a cross join, use `CROSS JOIN` .- that's what it's there for, and then it's **clear** that you really meant to have a cross join (and didn't just forget the join condition(s) .... ). It's all about **clearly** showing your intent

Comment: what is the status of the question? if it is solved, an answer should be chosen and accepted, in turn marking the question as solved.

Comment: @Kayaman hey, I'm now encountering a situation I need a cross join for. I have table for warehouses and table for items , and I need to set some attributes for every item along with every warehouse , for example `('warehouse_1','TVs'),('warehouse_1','washing_machines'),('warehouse_2','TVs'),('warehouse_2','washing_machines')` . I thought after your comment I will never need a cross join before 10 years :) . Sorry for bothering you after a while, but the conversation with you just jumped to my head while I'm building the new table :)

Comment: I doubt very much that you *need* a cross join. You're probably choosing it because your business logic has flaws and/or database schema is not properly normalized.

Comment: @Kayaman I have table 'Items'`id,name,bar-code,...etc` and table 'warehouses' `'id,name,location,..etc'` . Now I need to add another property to the items table, but unfortunately this property is changing depending on the warehouse , so I created a third table called 'item_warehouse_mm (item_id,warehouse_id,property)' and to fill it I needed a cross join like this `INSERT INTO item_warehouse_mm (item_id,warehouse_id) VALUES SELECT items.id,warehouse.id FROM items CROSS JOIN warehouses` . do you have any advises ? thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a cross join between the two tables as there is no join condition.

Assuming the reservation table has room_id FK which references id from room table, you can join like this:

```
select r.*,
    s.rn,
    s.cin
from room r
join reservation s on r.id = s.room_id
```

Always use proper explicit join syntax instead of comma based joins.

Comment: Why would you `always` use explicit joins? Implicit joins (for inner joins) are perfectly fine and make no difference performance-wise. For small queries like the one in the OP they are also way more easy to read as they don't clog up your code. Imho explicit joins only make sense for complicated queries with lots of differen tables involved.

Comment: @dazza - Comma based joins are so last decade. Explicit syntax is clear and modern. They are declarative as what you are really trying to do. Beginners mistake such as one OP did can be easily avoided when you know you are joining the tables, not just selecting from a bunch of tables.

Comment: @daZza - because best practices are a thing, so is code consistency.  Also lets agree to disagree on the "way more easy to read", as I typically read a query from top to bottom to determine what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

Your select statement results in a cross join / cartesian product.

Use a WHERE-clause!

```
SELECT room.*,reservation.rn,reservation.cin FROM room,reservation WHERE room.room_no = reservation.room_no
```

For more complicated joins I recommend using an explicit syntax with the appropriate keywords, although your implicit join is perfectly fine for this case (and performance wise implicit and explicit joins are the same).

To display unreserved rooms as well (so to keep results that do not satisfy the where-clause) you'll have to use an OUTER JOIN (LEFT or RIGHT depending on what you want to keep) like this:

```
SELECT room.*,reservation.rn,reservation.cin 
FROM room LEFT OUTER JOIN reservation 
ON room.room_no = reservation.room_no
```

Comment: yes, i get my answers with that but i also want to display the remaining vacant rooms.

Comment: In that case you'll have to use a LEFT JOIN. I'll update my answer

Comment: Thank u very much!

Answer (score 0):

For the first part you need a join and for second condition you  need union :

```
select r.Id,r.r_num,r.r_price,r.in_date,r.out_date,s.id as resId,s.r_num,s.cIn,s.cOut
   from room r
join reservation s on r. r_num = s. r_num
  union 
select r.Id,r.r_num,r.r_price,r.in_date,r.out_date,null as resId, null as r_num, null as cIn,null as cOut
  from room r
where r.in_date is null
```

union by default distinct the result if you need repeated rows just use     UNION ALL